# make an interface with datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am making a windows form application, a billing software. I want to make a interface like this on one of the forms:
There is a row of textboxes with about 5-7 textboxes, i fill the first textbox with a product ID which automatically populates the rest of the textboxes fetching data from appropriate tables and automatically generate a new row of textboxes, the first textbox from the new row being focussed for entering product ID. It should continue until i click a certain button which finalizes the bill. On clicking this button all these values should be updated to database in respective tables. How can I achieve this?
Can using datagrid help?

Comment: I have tried using grid view so far but got nothing.. Actually, I dont know how to start. Please help

Comment: Unless you find someone willing to write an entire program for you, you're going to need to work through it on your own. SO is really for helping with *specific* issues where people are stuck, not writing apps for people. I'd suggest reading a book, googling, reading articles online, etc... Then, when you're stuck on something specific, ask here.

Comment: ok, let me be more specific. I am using a grid view to enter the data, multiple rows and colums. Now i want this data to be updated to multiple tables in database. What should I do?

Comment: What database are you using? (MS SQL Server, RavenDB, Oracle, etc...) What technology will use use to talk to that database? (ADO.NET, Linq-to-SQL, Entity Framework, etc...) Once you know that, google: "SQL Server C#." Or there are many excellent books out there that explain exactly how to do this. The problem is that your question is still not specific. Indeed, "How do I communicate with a database" is a general topic, covered by many articles and books.

Comment: i know how to write to database, i am not new to this, but just stuck at a point. i came to SO just because I don't have anyone here to help me. Anyways, I am using C# as the programming lang, ADO.NET for communicating with Microsoft's SQL Express Editio 2008, that comes with Visual Studio 2010. I can easily add data to database, infact i have done it hundred times, but here it is different, I want to create space for data entry at runtime, row by row, and update that to DB at the end.

Comment: I want to make a form with the interface that we encounter when we create a new table in SQL server. We add a row and then a new row is automatically added for more data.

Comment: I can also describe in more detail what I am trying to do and what I am unable to do.

Comment: I think more detail needs to be provided. I'm indeed having a hard time understanding your exact problem.

Comment: this form would be used to create list of items sold in the shop. the first textbox would contain the product ID that would be entered by the user. As soon as the user enters the product ID, the second third and fourth textboxes get populated with more details about that particular product like, its name, price and total qty! also a new row of text boxes should be created for entry of another product ID. this should continue as long as user presses the Finalize button to generate the BILL.

Comment: So far i am able to create textboxes dynamically, at run time, but the problem I am facing is I cannot use the textboxes created. If you are unable to understand my problem, please tell me how can i fetch the text in a atextbox created dynamically!
I created it like, 

TextBox txt=new TextBox();
txt.Name="textbox"+i.ToString();

but when i use textbox1.Text, its not available there!!!

Comment: It sounds like you should create a Dictionary<int, Textbox>. Every time you need to dynamically add a textbox, do dictionary.Add(i, new TextBox()). Then you can access the textboxes that way: dictionary[i].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google "C# write to database" and click on one of the links, like these that came up when I did it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3554/Simple-Database-Application-Part-1

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1155/Simple-ADO-NET-Database-Read-Insert-Update-and-Del

Or go to amazon.com and search "c# database" and buy one of those books.